# pip is giving import error while doing any operation

Tags: pip, windows-10, importerror

I have already worked other methods but nothing works and i get this error.
i am on windows 10 currently

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
ImportError: cannot import name 'cmdoptions'`

Comment: Was it able to install pip.cmdoptions and why not?

Comment: for anything to related to pip command its showing same error..i even tried upgrading or downgrading but nothing works

Comment: I'm having the same issue, using conda 4.5.10 on a win10